# Tensorflow .pb file to coreml model: 'Unsupported Ops of type: AddV2'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, coreml, coremltools

I am trying to convert my tensorflow model(.pb file) obtained by retraining the mobilenet architecture to coreml model.
Initially I had tensorflow **1.14.0** everything worked perfectly. But when I upgraded the tensorflow to **2.0.0** and retrained the model, because of
deprecations python is adding 'AddV2' operation instead of 'Add'. Because of this I am getting an error during convertion as

> Unsupported Ops of type: AddV2

What can I do about this? Should I have to change the operation or tweak conversion code to support
the operation.

Comment: If you look at the release notes of [tfcoreml 1.1.0](https://github.com/tf-coreml/tf-coreml/releases/tag/1.1.0), it seems they added support for TensorFlow 2.x and `AddV2` there, among other things.

Comment: No it is not! https://github.com/tf-coreml/tf-coreml/blob/master/tfcoreml/_ops_to_layers.py I added manually in my system

Answer (score 0):

Although the tfcoreml==1.1.0 says it has added AddV2 operation to support tf 2.0.0 it has not.

https://github.com/tf-coreml/tf-coreml/releases/tag/1.1.0

Proof:

https://github.com/tf-coreml/tf-coreml/blob/master/tfcoreml/_ops_to_layers.py

This can be solved by adding AddV2 which does elementwise operation in the above script.